# OAuthException: active access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, stack-trace, access-token

Our app has so many calls to the facebook api, how can I output the error stack trace so we can see WHICH call to the API is causing the access token error?

OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I need to be able to pinpoint the LINE NUMBER that THREW the error above

Answer (score 0):

That error is returned by facebook graph api, so you could try to output your request your before you send it, and then output your response that way you will know. This error means that you didn't provided access token, witch must be present with every request to facebook if your using facebook graph api.